# Set and get username between activities

Tags: android

Here's the scenario.
I have:

A LOGIN activity

A SESSION where I have methods getUsername() and setUsername()

A GET activity where it is supposed to get the username.

Upon successful login in the Login Activity I have this line of code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Session obj = new Session();
```

and then in another method called tryLogin() i have this

```
obj.setUsername(mUsername);
```

In Session activity I have these codes:

```
public class Session extends Application {
String username;
int userid;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

public void setUsername(String user)
{
    this.username = user;
}
public String getUsername()
{
    return this.username;
}
```

and in the Activity that gets the username I have this line.

```
    Session obj = new Session();
    username =  obj.getUsername();
```

This doesn't work properly. BUT if I manually set the 'username' to some string in the SESSION activity like this:

```
public class Session extends Application {
    String username = "manually set the string";
```

Then the GET Activity gets the username just fine.
So I think it's safe to narrow down the issue to the setUsername from the login activity.

So what am i doing wrong here?

Thank you so much.
//
Android Beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public class Session extends Application {
     public static String username;
```

in your Session Activity.

Comment: This actually worked. 
I changed it to public static and accessed it like this:

Session.username = "blah blah"

but should I be concerned about what user370305 said about a new object being created all over again or ?

Comment: If you use public static on both your functions and classes, then you don't need to create an instance of the class. So you don't even need Session obj = new Session(). You can just use Session.username = "blah blah". or Session.getUsername()

Comment: Also, please choose this as the accepted answer if it worked.

Comment: Yes of course I see what you mean. I will accept your answer. Im just giving others time to give feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should set the value of method in Session class which extends Application as

```
((Session) yourActivityName.getApplication()).setUserName("user Nmae");
```

and access it as

```
((Session) yourActivityName.getApplication()).getUserName();
```

Comment: ((Session) this.getApplication()).setUsername("user Nmae"); 
This is what I tried but it still crashes on that line.

is there something else i need to declare? why does it crash?